# Nginx location does not work

Tags: angular, nginx

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name _;
access_log /data/wwwlogs/access_nginx.log combined;
root /data/wwwroot/default;
index index.html;

location /dist {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /dist/index.html;
}
```

I'm trying to configure my nginx server. I hope when I try to visit "ipaddress/dist/**anything**", all requests can be redirected to "ipaddress/dist/index.html". It is a requirement for routing of Angular2. However, I can only find 404 page. It seems "try_files" or "location /dist" does not work. What' wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

check out [redirect](https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/) directive.

```
server {
     listen 80;
     server_name localhost;
     access_log /data/wwwlogs/access_nginx.log combined;
     root /data/wwwroot/default;
     index index.html;

     location /dist {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /dist/index.html;
     }

     rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://localhost/dist/index.html permanent;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems directly redirect will lose the two-stage routing address. The solution provided by Angular is to use "location" and "try_files", but mine dosen't work. The nginx does not go to the last parm of "try_files" when it can not find "$uri".

Comment: can you try location / {...}?

Comment: no, try this `location / { try_files $uri /dist/index.html; }` what does it say?

Comment: yes I tried and when I visit "www.xxx.com/donotexist", it will appear 404 page instead of index.html. But if "try_files" works, it should be redirect to index.html.
`
location / {
        try_files $uri /index.html;
        }
`

Comment: 404 page still appears

Comment: where is `/dist/index.html` located in your filesystem?

Comment: /data/wwwroot/default/dist/index.html

Comment: yes I tried this also, and when i visit www.xx.com/donotexist , it will show 404, does it mean try_files does not work bc if works, when i visit something  do not exist in my file system, it will be redirect to www.xx.com/index.html

Comment: **edit**: try `location /dist { try_files $uri /index.html; }`

Comment: the same, always 404 when it cannot find the resource, but it should go to index when fail to find.

Comment: try `error_log /data/wwwlogs/error_nginx.log debug;` to figure out what is going on

Answer (score 0):

Your example works! Maybe you forgot to reload nginx service with new config?

Comment: did you tried to setup `error_log /data/wwwlogs/error_nginx.log debug;` to figure out what is going on?